# Authorization required for Client Registration Id

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webclient

I'm trying to setup an API that needs to comunicate with another service that requires the server to login using OAuth2.

I have the following files/configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations, ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepo) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                        clientRegistrations,
                        authorizedClientRepo);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("xxx");
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();
    }
}


@Configuration
public class WebSecurity {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange()
                .permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }
}


@RestController
public class RestTest {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public RestTest(WebClient webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Mono<String> obtainSecuredResource() {
        Mono<String> retrievedResource = webClient.get()
                .uri("https://apixxx.com/banks")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);

        return retrievedResource.map(string -> "We retrieved the following resource using Oauth: " + string);
    }
}
```

Properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxx.client-name=xxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxx.client-id=random
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxx.client-secret=random
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxx.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxx.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/xxx

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxx.token-uri=https://app.xxx.pt/oauth/access_token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxx.authorization-uri=https://app.xxx.pt/oauth
```

But when I send the request I get the following error:

[client_authorization_required] Authorization required for Client Registration Id: xxx

Thanks